# Use indirect range in linest formula

Tags: excel, range, formula

I am trying to use LINEST formula with variable starting coordinate:

```
'=LINEST((address(a24,3,4,true,"Copy raw data here")):C36,'Copy raw data here'!A3:A36)
```

where (address(a24,3,4,true,"Copy raw data here")) should generate "Copy raw data here'!C3. Excel doesn't like it.
How should I change it?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the `ADDRESS` function in `INDIRECT` like this

`=INDIRECT(address(a24,3,4,true,"Copy raw data here"))`

....but you are then creating a reference as a text string (with ADDRESS) and using INDIRECT to convert it back to a reference, perhaps easier to use INDEX like

`=INDEX('Copy raw data here'!C:C,A24)`

so in the larger formula that would be

`=LINEST(INDEX('Copy raw data here'!C:C,A24):C36,'Copy raw data here'!A3:A36)`

Comment: Hi Barry, thank you for the tip, unfortunately I still have #VALUE error. Let me elaborate a bit what I’m doing, probably overcomplicating things a lot. I have a 2 column data of laser driving current and corresponding output power. There is certain threshold in output power after which values increasing at much different rate than before that threshold but in linear fashion. I am setting criteria for the threshold as 3% of MAX output power. (please read next message as well)

Comment: (continuation)  So, what I want is to write LINEST function that as start data array will have the line number that corresponds to that 3% power value. I can have this columns in any order (I realized that Excel only finds corresponding values to the right of searched value). If you have any idea how this should be done please share it with me.
Thank you very much and kind regards, Sergei.